# i want to treat some parameters that ajax returns

Tags: javascript

i used XMLHTTPRequest like

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 /** responseText is not available yet */) {
      const statusCode = xhr.status
      const responseText = xhr.responseText

      /** blah blah */
    }
}
```

but now, i am requesting with Ajax like

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: payloads,
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    type: 'POST',
  })
```

how can i receive those statusCode and responseText?
and how can i treat them with same function.
i heard that add .done or .success functions,
but i don't know how are they different.

i'm waiting your kindness

Comment: search? did you search http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-post/

Comment: Are you sure you need to use POST and not GET?

Comment: but there is no way to receive responseText and statusCode.

Comment: of coures. i don't want to process with GET

Comment: try my answer, I've edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: payloads,
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    type: 'POST',
  }).done(function(data) { //fetches the data after AJAX call
      const statusCode = data.status;
      const responseText = data.responseText;
  });
```

Comment: i'll try this. giving you luck